# Consecutive Delimiters in StringTokenizer

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I have to tokenize the following String

```
12/12/2010:{content1:[{xyz,abc}],13/12/2010:{content2:[{xyz,abc},{content3:[{aa,bb}]}]
```

I nee to split up the above string if it has }] consequtively. So I did,

```
    String[] tokens = null;
StringTokenizer csvToken = new StringTokenizer(csvString,"]}");
tokens = new String[csvToken.countTokens()];
int tmp = 0;
while(csvToken.hasMoreTokens()) {
    tokens[tmp++] = csvToken.nextToken();
}
```

But it is not tokenizing as I expected.

```
12/12/2010:{content1:[{xyz,abc
,13/12/2010:{content2:[{xyz,abc
,{content3:[{aa,bb
```

But What I expect was,

```
12/12/2010:{content1:[{xyz,abc
,13/12/2010:{content2:[{xyz,abc},{content3:[{aa,bb
```

how Could I make the code to work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about String.split(String regex)?

```
String toDo = "12/12/2010:{content1:[{xyz,abc}],13/12/2010:{content2:[{xyz,abc},{content3:[{aa,bb}]}]";
String[] splitted = toDo.split("\\}\\]");
for (String s : splitted) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: it didn't? This exact code worked for me as you expected. E.g. two results

Comment: @d1x, you must append the last `s` to the previous `splitted`. See the **expected** output on the question.

Comment: Actually I have given the sample string as like my original Input. Yes I've tried and the above string works, but it's not working for the string

Comment: @d1x. Yes split is working fine for my original input also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seeing that there's no answers yet, my "quick fix" are as follows:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String csvString = "12/12/2010:{content1:[{xyz,abc}],13/12/2010:{content2:[{xyz,abc},{content3:[{aa,bb}]}]";

  String[] tokens = null;
  StringTokenizer csvToken = new StringTokenizer(csvString,"]}");
  tokens = new String[csvToken.countTokens() - 1];
  int tmp = 0;
  while(csvToken.hasMoreTokens()) {
   tokens[tmp++] = csvToken.nextToken();
   if (tmp == tokens.length) {
    tokens[tmp - 1]  += csvToken.nextToken();
   }
  }

  for (String token : tokens) {
   System.out.println(token);
  }

 }
}
```

Personally, I'll use  `String.split()` method and use my solution "idea" as above. Or, if you're brave, use regular expressions.

**PS** Code tested and worked....

Output:

> 12/12/2010:{content1:[{xyz,abc 
>   ,13/12/2010:{content2:[{xyz,abc,{content3:[{aa,bb